# How to modify discord.js v12 for user token

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I know selfbots are against TOS, and i know you can get banned for doing so.
I am developing my client, but when I try to login with user token, an error occurs

```
Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
```

My token is valid, and v11 working.
How to modify latest version of discord.js for using user token?

UPD 1: code

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const token = 'mfa.token.of.my.account';

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Make sure you pass in the token as a string in `.login()`

Comment: token string is valid, just in discord.js v12 removed user token support

Comment: Can you provide us with the code you have tried to login with?

Comment: updated post, added code

Comment: Have you tried regenerating your token the pasting it in again?

Comment: yes, the problem is not in the token, the problem is in discord.js, support for user tokens is discontinued in v12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant in discord.js you have to use [discord.js-user](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-user)

discord.js will give you an invalid token error if you try to use a user token to login.