# Discord bot how to login with personal account token with Node.js?

Tags: node.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const talkedRecently = new Set();

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Bot is ready!!");
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author.id != client.user.id) {
        if (talkedRecently.has(message.author.id)) {

        } else {
            message.author.send('Yo');
            talkedRecently.add(message.author.id);
            setTimeout(() => {talkedRecently.delete(message.author.id);}, 1800000);
        }
    }
});

client.login(<TOKEN>)
```

This source code work normally with token bot i want to login with personal account token what should i use or do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify discord.js v12 for user token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64194994/how-to-modify-discord-js-v12-for-user-token)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Discord doesn't support this kind of use and actually forbids it.
This is mostly related to the **Security** and **Regulation** of the users and the usage of the API:

You can read about it [here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-).

> The question regarding "self bots" has come up here and there, and we'd like to make our stance clear:
>
> Discord's API provides a separate type of user account dedicated to automation, called a bot account. Bot accounts can be created through the applications page, and are authenticated using a token (rather than a username and password). Unlike the normal OAuth2 flow, bot accounts have full access to all API routes without using bearer tokens, and can connect to the Real Time Gateway. **Automating normal user accounts (generally called "self-bots") outside of the OAuth2/bot API is forbidden, and can result in an account termination if found.**

Answer (score 1):

They have removed support for user token (self bot) from discord.js in v12 and looking at the [commit](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/2559) they have removed quite a lot from the package.

After digging a bit in the discord.js package found a way where you can overwrite this functionality by doing.

```
const client = new Discord.Client({_tokenType: ''});
```

This will remove the prefix `bot` when making a call to discord gateway and client will connect successfully.

This is purely for educational purpose and should be used responsibly.

P.s They are going to modify some other stuff too in the apis to make it impossible.